# Postgresql: why can't you drop a role with privileges that does not own any ressource?

Tags: postgresql

I'm confused by the nomenclature around roles and privileges with postgresql.

Given a stock `postgresql` install, if I do this:

```
postgres=# create database foo;
CREATE DATABASE
```

Now, there is a database.

```
postgres=# create role bar;
CREATE ROLE
```

Now, there is a user. I can delete it:

```
postgres=# drop role bar;
DROP ROLE
```

And it's gone, and I can recreate it again.

```
postgres=# create role bar;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# grant all privileges on database foo to bar;
GRANT
```

So this role does not own anything. (Since there is nothing to own.)
The database existed *before* the role. The way I understand it, it's an independent entity.
And you've just "GRANT"-ed the role "bar" to do some things with this database. 
Plain english. Pretty logical.

Then you changed your mind, and remove the role:

```
postgres=# drop role bar;
ERROR:  role "bar" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it
DETAIL:  privileges for database foo
```

"What the what ? What do you mean 'some objects depend on it' ? THERE IS NO OBJECT YET !!!", you ask.

As I understand it, the answer lies here:

```
postgres=# \l
                                     List of databases
     Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |     Access privileges     
--------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------
 foo          | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres             +
              |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres    +
              |          |          |             |             | bar=CTc/postgres
```

So the "ressource" that depends on you is the "privilege" itself.
So you can remove the privilege, and *after that*, drop the role:

```
postgres=# revoke all on database foo from bar;
REVOKE
postgres=# \l
                                     List of databases
     Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |     Access privileges     
--------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------
 foo          | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres             +
              |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
postgres=# drop user bar;
DROP ROLE
```

So my question is: *why* ? In this situation, something is preventing postgresql from doing the (obvious / expected / arguably less confusing)  thing, and "cascading" the dropping of "privileges", too.

What could it be ?

It might simply be a confusing error message over a n00b issue, but I suspect something more fundamental...